# Where to store images for a SourceForge wiki page?

Tags: sourceforge

I am developing an open source application under the [SourceForge web](http://sourceforge.net/). I am currently working on the requirements specification of my app. I created a wiki page for that purpose. There is a text scenario for every use case on that page.

What I would need is to append a wireframe (e.g. an image) to some of the use cases. The wireframe is too big to be included into the page directly as an image. Rather it should be saved separately (ideally inside my GIT repository) and then linked from the wiki page.

I wasn't able to find out how to get a URL for a single file inside my GIT repository - I only found a link to a preview of the file inside the repository browser, which is not what I need. Ideally the link should be persistent across modifications of the image in the repository, so that the links inside a page would be valid even after I change the file inside the repository.

Another option would be to append the images to the wiki page as attachments. I tried that but wiki shows previews of all attachments above the page and they are too many of them.

What is the best way to append images (such as wireframes) to a wiki page on SourceForge?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the wireframes in your git repository, the best solution is to use the "raw" links in the gitweb viewer for your URLs, e.g. http://exampleproject.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=exampleproject/projdir;a=blob_plain;f=wireframe1234.png;hb=HEAD - you can get these URLs by selecting Code > Git Browse from the SourceForge project page, then clicking on "tree" and finally copying the link URL from the "raw" link next to the wireframe file you want.

If your project is not using git, another solution is to upload the image file to the Files area of your SourceForge project.

You should do this in a sub-folder, to avoid cluttering the Files page with all sorts of things that most people will not want to download.  After creating a "wireframes" folder using the "Add Folder" button, and uploading your wireframe images, refresh the page and then click on the link, which takes you to a download mirror page.  Copy the "direct link" in the header - this will be a URL like https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/exampleproject/wireframes/wireframe1234.png?r=&ts=1326447090&use_mirror=voxel and use this as the URL for the image in your wiki.

Disadvantages of the "Files" approach are that you will need to re-upload every time you have a changed wireframe, and after you do that, SourceForge will suggest "Looking for the latest version? Download wireframe1234.png (17.2 kB)" at the top of the Files page to everyone.  Also, if the SourceForge mirror site stops mirroring, you would need to update all the &use_mirror=xxx in the URLs (this is not very likely, though).